# Explain why $4$ cannot be replaced by $5$ in part a)

Tags: combinatorics, orthogonality, combinatorial-proofs, latin-square

a)
Construct a Latin square of order $8$ in which the submatrix
formed from the first $4$ rows and $4$ columns is the addition table
for $Z_4$.

b) Explain why $4$ cannot be replaced by $5$ in part a)

For a) my Latin square of order $8$ I had:
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 &3 &4&5&6&7\\
1&2&3&0&5&4&7&6\\
2&3&0&1&6&7&4&5\\
3&0&1&2&7&6&5&4\\
4&5&6&7&0&1&2&3\\
5&6&7&4&1&2&3&0\\
6&7&4&5&2&3&0&1\\
7&4&5&6&3&0&1&2
\end{bmatrix}

For b) I was trying to show that $N(i) \geq r+s-n$ fails, where N(i) is the number of i's in the rxs rectangle, and rxs is the $4\times4$ submatrix, and n is the order of the Latin square.
However, I have $4\geq 5+5-8 \Longrightarrow 4 \geq 3$ which is true and I'm stuck here

Comment: It can not be done. Consider last three columns and say we could construct 5x5 latin square on top left submatrix. Then last three columns would have $6, 7, 8$.

We actually need to fill $6, 7, 8$ in last three columns for atleast $5$ rows. But only possible shufflings are $6, 7, 8$ or $7, 8, 6$ or $8, 6, 7$. After that one column will have repetition.

Answer (score 1):

The formula $N(i) \geq r+s-n$ comes from Ryser's criteria about the extensibility of an $r \times s$ matrix to an $n \times n$ Latin square.  It works for this problem, but your values of $N(i)$ are incorrect.

> **Ryser's criteria**:  Let $X$ be an $r \times s$ matrix with (a) no repeated symbols in rows nor columns, and (b) symbols from $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$.  Let $N(i)$ denote the number of copies of symbol $i$ in $X$.  Then $X$ can be completed to a $n \times n$ Latin square if and only if $N(i) \geq r+s−n$ for all symbols $i \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

For the question, we have a $5 \times 5$ subsquare $X$, so $r=s=5$, and we're working in a Latin square of order $8$, so $n=8$.  Since $X$ is a $5 \times 5$ subsquare, some symbols $i$ have $N(i)=5$ and others have $N(i)=0$.

For the symbols $i$ with $N(i)=0$, we have $N(i) = 0 \not\geq 2 = r+s−n$, so Ryser's criteria is not satisfied (the inequality needs to be true for all symbols); we conclude a $5 \times 5$ subsquare cannot be extended to a $8 \times 8$ Latin square.  (But if we had a $4 \times 4$ subsquare instead, then the right-hand side is $0 = r+s−n$, and Ryser's criteria would be satisfied for all symbols.)

---

It's not necessary to use Ryser's criteria: we can just count instead.  We break up an $n \times n$ Latin square with an $a \times a$ subsquare $X$ (where $a < n$) as follows:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{a \times a} & Y_{a \times (n-a)} \\
Z_{(n-a) \times a} & W_{(n-a) \times (n-a)}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
(Here the indices indicate the dimensions of the blocks.)

Since $X$ is a subsquare, any symbol $x$ in $X$ occurs exactly $a$ times in $X$: exactly once in each row.  Thus, $x$ does not occur in $Y$ (or we have two copies of $x$ in a row, contradicting the Latin property).  The last $n-a$ columns each contain an $x$, and since they don't occur in $Y$, they must occur in $W$.  We conclude that $W$ contains $n-a$ copies of $x$.

Since this is true for every symbol $x$ in $X$, the submatrix $W$ contains $n-a$ copies of each of the $a$ distinct symbols in $X$.  So $W$ has exactly $(n-a)^2$ cells containing at least $(n-a)a$ symbols.  This is a contradiction when $(n-a)^2 < (n-a)a$, or equivalently when $a > n/2$.

The general conclusion is that a Latin square of order $n$ cannot have a (Latin) subsquare of order $a$ satisfying $n/2 < a < n$.  Ryser's criteria generalizes this result.

In particular, a Latin square of order $8$ cannot have a (Latin) subsquare of order $5$.